# Last activity time vs Original Post Time

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

Would it be possible to show when a post was originally made as well as the last time there was activity on the post?  (EDIT: From the home page, without having to go into the question itself.)

Sometimes, the post is a few years old, but someone either made an edit or a new member answered/commented bringing the post back to the top of the queue (An example: [Can a Windows 7 DVD be used to install both 32-bit and 64-bit versions?](https://superuser.com/questions/191791/can-a-windows-7-dvd-be-used-to-install-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions)).

I think it would be an asset to see whether the post is relatively new, or if it's being cleaned up.

Another request that ties along with this is the ability to see at a glance whether the recent activity was an edit (which means that I'm personally not interested) or a new answer has been given (which I may find of interest).

Comment: While it doesn't show the original post date in the list, you can use the number of views as a (very stupid, very error-prone) indicator for question age.

Comment: To be honest I think that'd just add noise. We shouldn't really care if a question is old or not. If it's bumped, that's mostly for a good reason and we want people to look at it, regardless of its age. The real solution to that clean-up problem would be to allow minor non-bumping edits that are reviewed through other means (meaning, not by being visible on the front page).

Comment: The date is probably not shown because we want to prevent the kind of "dead thread" problems on other forums. That's why there are rewards for editing and answering old questions and why we close new questions usually as duplicates of older questions. Changes need to be reviewed by the community just like new questions are. There's simply no reason to show this information, because it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @slhck That's a lot better than my idea.

Comment: @Kruug Unfortunately, [nobody cares](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116809/the-flip-side-of-no-minor-edits/116810#116810). A workaround would be to use the `/questions?sort=newest` list, which does not show changes questions like the front page does.